# Как реализовать передачу данных между формами и просмотр этих же данных, придерживаясь паттерну mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Изучаю WPF, приложение строю по принципам паттерна mvvm. Не использую никакие стандартные шаблоны, все сам, чтобы четко осознать принцип построения приложений. Столкнулся с проблемой:
Есть у меня две формы, `form1` и `form2`. На `form1` находится кнопка для открытия `form2`, на которой я заполняю данные, после чего, хочу отправить эти данные для вывода на `form1`. Но не получается это реализовать.
Для открытия `form2` из `form1` я банально создаю экземпляр класса:

```
form2 form = new form2()
{
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()
};
```

По такой же схеме, в `form2`, после нажатия кнопки "отправить данные" (нажатие кнопки реализовано от интерфейса `ICommand`) я хотел бы, чтобы `textBox`у `form1` выводил эти данные сразу же.

```
form1 form = new form1 { DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel() };

<TextBox x:Name="testText" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Text="{Binding TestText1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

---

То есть я тут столкнулся с 2мя проблемами: сама передача данных и сразу же просмотр этих данных в `form1`. 
Для передачи я пробовал в конструктор `form1` посылать текст, там создать открытое свойство, но после моего кода `form.Show()` вывести это в `textbox` не получается, как будто после создания экземпляра контекст еще не меняется, а ждет окончания работы метода.

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему (передача и просмотр)? Я все вызовы те делал во ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот это:

```
form2 form = new form2()
{
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()
};
```

скорее всего неправильно. Вы не должны создавать *отдельную*, новую, ни с чем не связанную VM для второго окна (в WPF, кстати, элементы верхнего уровня принято называть *окнами*). Проще всего, наверное, отдавать *одну и ту же* VM обеим окнам. Например, так:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public MainVM { get; } = new MainWindowViewModel();

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new form1() { DataContext = MainVM }.Show();
    }
}

// ...

var mainVM = ((App)Application.Current).MainVM;
var f2 = new form2() { DataContext = mainVM };
```

И обязательно уберите из `App.xaml` атрибут `StartupUri`!

---

И я бы очень не советовал объявлять VM в XAML. Согласно паттерну MVVM, View не имеет право руководить VM, тем более создавать её.

Comment: увы, слабо понимаю, я через class App запускаю форму и там же привязываю datacontext (изначально): 
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            var mw = new MainWindow
            {
                DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()
            };

            mw.Show();
        }
    }
Пробовал ваше ввести, ошибки, хотя я слабо понимаю, о чем это ((

Comment: @Bruceee: (1) Не делайте этого в конструкторе, делайте в `OnStartup`, как написано в ответе. (2) А что непонятно? В ответе всё же есть. Вы **не должны** создавать разные экземпляры `MainWindowViewModel`, иначе они, очевидно, будут несвязаны между собой.

Comment: а некорректно будет написать? [form2 form = new form2()
{
    DataContext = this
};]

Comment: @Bruceee: Ну это смотря по тому, чем у вас будет `this`, очевидно.

Comment: Насчет создания экземпляра datacontext  я вас понял, спасибо, мелочь, а не заметил! но про onstartup слабо понял суть того, что написали, у меня показывает ошибки, но постараюсь разобраться. спасибо вам!

Comment: @Bruceee: Пожалуйста! А какие ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

Объявите Вашу модель дочернего окна в XAML и воспользуйтесь связыванием её свойств со свойствами основной модели.

Comment: То есть, я только изучаю, слабо понимаю о чем Вы. Создать класс для хранения данных, но как связать "её свойств со свойствами основной модели."?  спасибо вам за ваш ответ!

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ ибо в текущем виде он больше похож на комментарий.